# Did Ibn al-Haytham write anything about his experiments that is general enough to be seen as prefiguring the scientific method?

Tags: biographical-details, discoveries, philosophy-of-science

Ibn al-Haytham is considered one of the first experimenters. Since he was also a kind of philosopher did he write anything close in meaning and generality to the scientific method?

Comment: Considering that ["the scientific method"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-method/) does not exist it is unclear what Ibn al-Haytham was supposed to be close to "in meaning and generality". His experimental methodology is complex, and many aspects of it are controversial even without artificial modernizations. See e.g. an overview in [Ghassemi's recent thesis, pp. 40-50](https://repository.library.georgetown.edu/bitstream/handle/10822/1059420/Ghassemi_georgetown_0076D_14407.pdf)

Comment: I think trying to find commonality between Ibn al-Hatham and the beginnings of modern science is a mistake. The same goes for aristotle, or whatever other ancient philosophers you wish. The people, cultures, desired outcomes, etc are all very different, and when looking back historically its most useful to understand the influences and culture, and the methods as unique, or else we might project our own processes or logic or beliefs onto the past where it does not belong. Theres my philosophy for the day!

Comment: @SamGallagher But if the notion of modern science evolved from the works of people like al-Hatham in some fashion then there are chances that they have some commonalities with science in a similar way the hominids have some commonalities with humans

Comment: @GEP Agree completely, if someone had influence and was part of the evolution of thought, then this is a great question to ask. I was only skeptical of his influence, and decided to get on my soap box!